# Sleep on a method but not the entire program in c#

Tags: c#

I am wondering how to make my method wait without using Thread.sleep(time), look at this example:

```
    public askRessource(systemRessource ressource, int time)
    {
        acquireRessource(ressource, time);

        Thread.Sleep(time * 1000);

        freeRessource(ressource);
    }
```

This is my code using Thread.sleep and here is my main class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        systemRessource disk1 = new systemRessource("disk1");

        askRessource ask1 = new askRessource(disk1, 3);

        systemRessource ram1 = new systemRessource("ram1");

        ask1 = new askRessource(ram1, 7);

        systemRessource ram2 = new systemRessource("ram2");

        ask1 = new askRessource(disk1, 3);

        systemRessource disk3 = new systemRessource("disk3");

        askRessource ask2 = new askRessource(disk3, 6);


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

But now look at what happens in output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzONK.png)

It will start with ask1 askRessource (disk1,3) so it will do ask1.acquireRessource then it will sleep for 3 seconds and then ask1.freeRessource and then keep going with ask1 askRessource(ram1,7) and so on but my problem is that I would like my program to do that output :

> ask1.acquireRessource(disk1, 3); 
>   ask1.acquireRessource(ram1, 7);
>   ask2.acquireRessource(disk3, 6);
>   all at the same time and then after 3 second :
>   ask1.freeRessource(disk1); 
>   after 6 second: ask2.freeRessource(disk3);
>   and after 7 second: ask1.freeRessource(ram1);

So I think that I will need to use something else than `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backgroundworker for each systemRessource. This enables you to work with seperate threads, that you can also sleep independently.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you getting [Classic Race Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). To be sure i need to see `acquireRessource` and `freeRessource`. I suppose that it's async funcitons, and sometimes one going to start before previous has completed.
Hints to solve you problem:

1. ready about Task and async/await pattern.
2. Read about thread syncronization: `lock`, `Monitor`, `Semaphore`

Comment: I cannot see any evidence of multiple threads being used here. I think the problem is much simpler than that. Each call to AskResource is blocking and takes "time" seconds to return. They are asked sequential so the first must finish before the second starts and so on